# How to create a rule to redirect users to specific content according to their email domain?

Tags: 8, rules, emails, redirection

I'm trying to setup the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module in D8, but I'm unable to do so. I want to redirect users, according to their email domain they used to register themselves on my website, to specific pages:

Example:

- User has signed up with email @gmail.com -> redirected to `node/1`.
- User has signed up with email @yahoo.com -> redirected to `node/2`.
- User has signed up with email @aol.com -> redirected to `node/1`.
- User has signed up with email @xxxxx.com -> redirected to `node/1`.
- Etc.

Can anyone show me how to do it?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63102/discussion-on-question-by-hsilva-rules-module-how-to-redirect-users-to-specific).